# Can't find USB /dev mounting

Tags: drivers, usb, mount

I have this dongle which I suppose to have a /dev/tty* and I haven't.
I'm able to see in dmesg when I plug it:

```
[  421.946296] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  422.104243] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=55d4, bcdDevice= 4.42
[  422.104286] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  422.104291] usb 1-2: Product: SONOFF Zigbee 3.0 USB Dongle Plus V2
[  422.104294] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ITEAD
[  422.104297] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 20231101112012
```

But there is no `/dev/tty*`.

I can see it also with `lsusb`:

```
lsusb -vt
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=, 12M
        ID 1a86:55d4 QinHeng Electronics 
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=, 12M
        ID 1a86:55d4 QinHeng Electronics
```

The dongle works because when I plug in other machine I'am able to use it.

My env:

```
uname -a
Linux freevm 5.15.0-91-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:29:11 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

---

UPDATE

It seems the distro I was using haven't the usb serial driver. I did a fresh install of Debian and now is it working fine.

Thank you all for your reply

Comment: 1. Debian is off-topic, so I'll assume one PC is debian and the other Ubuntu 2. Is `lsusb` the same on both? 3. Did you add a udev rule on the working one?

Comment: Google suggests the applicable driver is **cp210x** - do you see a `cp210x.ko` kernel module under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/` ?

Comment: @ArturMeinild afaik the `debian_version` is fine, it's provided by the `base-files` package and reflects the upstream version. It's different from the `lsb-release` file.

Comment: @steeldriver you're right. But then in this case it's confusing information, since it can lead people to believe that this is a Debian system. `lsb_release -a` would be a better command to include. I'm editing it out of the question.

Comment: Please remove your close votes, this is a normal Ubuntu system. Reference to `debian_version` has been removed.